# What's the English terminology for a "section" set?

Tags: terminology

I'm translating the terminology from my native language into English. The closest placeholder I have to the word is a "section" set, but I couldn't find anything like that online.

We say that $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is a section if it does not contain a maximal member, and that every $a \in A$ and every $q\in \mathbb{Q}$ allow for:

$x \leq a \Rightarrow x \in A$

Comment: Downward closed possibly?

Comment: If additionally $A\ne\emptyset$ and $A\ne\Bbb Q$, this looks like a *Dedekind cut*.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, that's it. The definition fits. Also think the definition may be flawed, as $x$ should be replaced with $q$.

Comment: Section is also used in English.